# HI how can save or store the state/step in mat-stepper ,when i refresh the page it come from initial step/beginning

Tags: angular, mat-stepper

I have put many reative form on mat-steps in angular 12 but it comes in initial step on refresh page,how can i save the state whereas i refresh the page,any idea?

[image]

```
 <mat-stepper labelPosition="bottom" linear  #stepper>
    <mat-step [stepControl]="selForm"></mat-step>
    <mat-step [stepControl]="indentityGrp" [editable]="isEditable"></mat-step>
    <mat-step [stepControl]="address" [editable]="isEditable2" class="border"></mat-step>
    <mat-step [stepControl]="member" [editable]="isEditable3"></mat-step>
</mat-stepper>
```

Comment: Or with a query parameter...

Answer (score 2):

Option 1: send it to the server and store the temporary form data there and fetch it on every app initialize.

Option 2: save on `localStorage` something like :

```
this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(data => localStorage.setItem('form', data))
```

and in your component

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.form.fetchData(localStorage.getItem('form'))
}
```

Comment: Ok mr eli but i m not loosing my data on refresh ,it comes on step 1 after refresh ,suppose that i filled the address form successfully when i refresh the page it will come on  select form step